# В $onDestroy отменить destroy

Tags: angularjs

Есть ли способ в `$onDestroy` отменить собственно `destroy` (что-то типа `e.preventDefault`)? А потом при определенных действиях его запустить?

Comment: в документации к компонентам не описаны никакие ужимки и прыжки с `$onDestroy`. расскажи подробнее о проблеме, которую ты решаешь.

Comment: @norbornen Мне нужно при переходе на другую вкладку вывести сообщение, что у юзера есть несохраненные данные и спросить, что он хочет с ними сделать. Если он жмёт cancel, то никуда не переходить.

Comment: так из описания проблемы очевидно, что отложенный дестрой тут тоже ничего не решит и что нужно встраиваться в обработчик клика на таб, тот самый, в котором уже поднимается sweetAlert

Comment: лучше выкладывай сюда твой код связанный с табами, посмотрим на него

Comment: @norbornen, мне за минуту до вашего ответа уже поменяли задачу, так что я переписала коммент, извиняюсь. и таб вообще находится в другом контроллере. то есть единственный способ - это организовать передачу данных между этими двумя контроллерами?

Comment: где-то над этим хозяйством существует ng-form?